# Anniversary from contacts in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm able to get birth dates from contacts but not the anniversary dates on iPhone. I have used KABPersonAnniversaryLabel but it is giving an error.

Comment: @NitinGohel He is asking about retrieving the value, not to save

Comment: @ambuj Can you pls add some code and describe the error you are facing

Comment: ABMultiValueRef anni= ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAnniversaryLabel);  nslog(@"%@",anni); so it is throwing exception and in console lldb is written

Comment: and same error when  NSDate anni= ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAnniversaryLabel);

Comment: Try ABMultiValueRef anniversaries = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonDateProperty); kABPersonAnniversaryLabel will return CFStringRef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will fetch anniversary for all contacts,

```
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(people); i++) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
        ABMultiValueRef anniversaries = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonDateProperty);
        NSString *anniversaryLabel;
        for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(anniversaries); j++) {
            anniversaryLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(anniversaries, j);
            if([anniversaryLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonAnniversaryLabel])
            {
                NSDate *anniversaryDate=(NSDate *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(anniversaries, j);
                NSLog(@"%@",anniversaryDate);
            }
        }
        CFRelease(anniversaries);
    }
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    CFRelease(people);
```

Comment: ABMultiValueRef anniversaries = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonDateProperty); it solved my problem but I want that to print in a label and after converting ib to nsstring also it is not getting solved

Comment: @ambujshukla what you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to print the anniversary date on a label when user click on one of his contact.

Comment: You got the NSDate right?, then convert it to NSString using NSDateFormatter and then display

Comment: NSString *dateStr = string;
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [df setDateFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"]];
    NSDate *_date = [df dateFromString:dateStr];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",_date); I have used this but getting null value

Comment: anniversaryDate is not in the format dd MMM yyyy HH:mm