# Accessing kABAnniversaryLabel and applying it to date Format

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, addressbook

I am attempting to access the anniversary date property from the contacts in address book. I have already accessed other properties such as the name and company. myPerson was created from a custom class, and it has an NSDate property called date.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook2  = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
NSMutableArray *people = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook2);
ABRecordRef r = (__bridge ABRecordRef)([people objectAtIndex:i]);
NSDateFormatter *dF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dF setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dS = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dS=[dF dateFromString:(__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(r, kABPersonAnniversaryLabel))];
myPerson.date = dS;
```

The application builds but gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and an value conversion issue warning on the line where dS gets its value.

Comment: Contact dates are like phone numbers and email addresses. A user can have more than one. You need to get the list of dates and find the one with the desired label.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234029/anniversary-from-contacts-in-iphone/14235238#14235238 for how to find the anniversary date of a contact.

Comment: BTW - you really need to update your code to deal with checking and getting permission to access the user's contacts.

Comment: I actually have much more code than this that deals with getting permission I just condensed it to put in this question