# How to get Birthday and Anniversary labels from Contact Framework in iOS- Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

There might be duplication for this question

I did some R & D for get these results. But, currently i am using XCode 7.3 for that purpose i use Contact Framework only not ABAddressBook Framework.

For getting Anniversary Label using AddressBook Framework: [**Anniversary from contacts in iPhone**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234029/anniversary-from-contacts-in-iphone)

how can i get these results using Contacts Framework and how about birthdays list?

Answer (score 1):

Add this keys for getting birthdays while fetching contacts:-

```
let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey]
```

Comment: ThanQ @Vizllx, What about  Anniversary Label?

Answer (score 1):

A `CNContact`'s anniversary does not have it's own key. If it exists, it resides as a date component value in the contact's `[CNLabeledValue<NSDateComponents>]` array via the `CNContactDatesKey`. You have to extract it yourself.

Here's a short example to grab it:

**Swift 3:**

```
let store = CNContactStore()
let keys = [CNContactDatesKey as CNKeyDescriptor]
let containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier()
let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: containerId)

func fetchContacts() -> [CNContact]? {
    do {
        return try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keys)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}

let contacts = fetchContacts()

// Grab the first contact as an example
if let contact = contacts?.first {
    // Filter through the contact's dates array to find the one labeled "Anniversary"
    let anniversary = contact.dates.filter { date -> Bool in
        guard let label = date.label else { return false }
        return label.contains("Anniversary")
        }.first?.value as? DateComponents

    // The final date
    let date = anniversary?.date
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


self.groupOfContacts = [@[] mutableCopy];
[self getAllContact];

self.phoneNumberArr = [@[] mutableCopy];

for (CNContact *contact in self.groupOfContacts) {

    NSArray *thisOne = [[contact.phoneNumbers valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"digits"];


    // like this way you can pick different info like b'day and anniversary
    [self.phoneNumberArr addObjectsFromArray:thisOne];
}

NSLog(@"%@",self.phoneNumberArr);
NSLog(@"%@",self.groupOfContacts[0]);
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}

-(void)getAllContact{


if ([CNContactStore class]) {


    CNContactStore *addressBook = [[CNContactStore alloc]init];

    NSArray *keysToFetch = @[CNContactBirthdayKey,CNContactNamePrefixKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactRelationsKey,CNContactDatesKey];

    CNContactFetchRequest *fetchRequest =  [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc]initWithKeysToFetch:keysToFetch];

    [addressBook enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil usingBlock:^(CNContact * _Nonnull contact, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        [self.groupOfContacts addObject:contact];
    }];
}

}
```

You can do something like this change keys as per requirements. hope this will help :)